# How to make multiple image views using one piece of code

Tags: ios, image, swift

I have created this code and I want to know how to make more than one imageViews, created in different spots without having to rewrite it all. How would I do this? This is my code so far:

```
var imageView = UIImageView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.view.frame.width)))-50, CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.view.frame.height))), 100, 100)
    imageView.animationImages = [UIImage(named:"image1")!,UIImage(named:"image2")!,UIImage(named:"image3")!,UIImage(named:"image2")!]
    imageView.animationDuration = 0.5
    imageView.startAnimating()
    self.view.addSubview(aiCell)
}
```

Comment: How about a counted for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a function that takes a UIImage as a parameter and performs all the lines of code on it. So declare it like:

```
func configureImageView (imageView: UIImageView){
//your code here
}
```

To use this function on several different image views:

```
var imageView1 = UIImage()
var imageView2 = UIImage()
var imageView3 = UIImage()
```

And in `viewDidLoad`:

```
configureImageView(imageView1)
configureImageView(imageView2)
configureImageView(imageView3)
```